# How do I transition from test ads to real ads when I launch my app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storekit

I am using a test ad and loading it through a test device. I am about to put my app on the app store so that test device won't exist. I know I need to change my ad key to the real one, but how should I change the code so that it loads on the users device and not a test device?

```
func createInterstitialAd() -> GADInterstitial? {

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    guard let interstitial = interstitial else {
        return nil
    }

    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    interstitial.load(request)
    interstitial.delegate = self


    return interstitial

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can’t you just edit the production app ID into your function before you deploy it? As stated in the Admob interstitial docs, “Just make sure you replace it with your own ad unit ID before publishing your app.”

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial

```
func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
  var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
  interstitial.delegate = self
  interstitial.load(GADRequest())
  return interstitial
}
```

Comment: Yeah I plan on editing the ID, but I'm wondering about the test device that I request. Do I remove that entire request? Should it just be "interstitial.load"?

Comment: Or maybe I just remove request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]?

Comment: It's tough because I can't test if it works until my app is on the app store :(

Comment: I feel. To be honest, I don’t know how if it will work either but I suppose If you follow the documentation closely or ask a question on the Firebase hotline you should be good